# DrUpdate.dll error in sfc /scannow

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, sfc

I have an issue with sfc /scannow. It finishes the verification process and informs me of errors there were unable to be fixed. I looked into CBS.log file and I found four entries related to drupdate.dll. As I understand, this is related with driver updates over windows update?
I'm running 
Win 10 Pro x64.

AMD A6 5200

4GB DDR3 RAM

SATA 500GB HDD

This is a snippet of that error

```
2016-03-11 18:44:18, Info                  CSI    00003cfe@2016/3/11:17:44:18.431 Primitive installers committed for repair
2016-03-11 18:44:18, Info                  CSI    00003cff [SR] Verify complete
2016-03-11 18:44:18, Info                  CSI    00003d00 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2016-03-11 18:44:18, Info                  CSI    00003d01 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2016-03-11 18:44:23, Info                  CSI    00003d02 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:12]"DrUpdate.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-ServicingStack, version 10.0.10586.113, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, file cannot be checked
2016-03-11 18:44:24, Info                  CSI    00003d03@2016/3/11:17:44:24.310 Primitive installers committed for repair
```

I tried using dism /checkhealth (not the precise command, I don't know it from my head). What else can I do?

I tried asking MS support but they give me useless advice. The reason I used sfc /scannow is because KB3140768 Cumulative update fails to install. Also I tried manually replacing the drupdate.dlls that I have found and they were 1kb in size. I replaced them with the ones from the ISO image of Win 10 and still the same error occurs in sfc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download the Update KB3139907](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=KB3139907), use 7zip to extract the MSU. Now use expand.exe to extract the KB3139907.CAB:

```
expand -F:* C:\Windows10.0-KB3139907-x64.cab C:\Windows10.0-KB3139907-x64
```

Now run `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:C:\Windows10.0-KB3139907-x64 /LimitAccess` to restore the Dll.

Comment: btw on my question, `findstr /c:"[SR]" CBS.log >sfcdetails.txt` did not work (question was deleted)

Comment: @interwebz your WGA question? what fails? Share the CBS.log so that I can take a look at it.

Comment: still says accessdenied. even after i copied the folder to the desktop and used admin cmd to run the above command. `FINDSTR: Cannot open CBS.log`

Comment: @interwebz share the complete folder (onedrive, dropbox, other 1 click hoster)

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=59365BA8C6A5C96C!168&authkey=!AOTyq65Cbr_LM2Q&ithint=folder%2ccab

Comment: @interwebz in your created sfcdetails.txt it shows hat sfc was able to fix all files **All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired**. In the CBS.log I see ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT. your windows seams to be damaged. Look if you can install this update (or already have it): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2966583 If you have it or can install it, run later this command: **DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth** https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2015/07/23/the-new-and-improved-checksur/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxyNrkCNr48KUGFtT2F5TFQ2OFU

Comment: @interwebz there are tons of registry keys missing. looks you used a crappy registry cleaner tool. don't do this. **Backup all personal data!!!!!!!!!!!** and use the recovery function of your device to restore Windows. check the manual for the steps

Comment: haha, i always felt like something was really really wrong. Thanks for the help anyways!